# Remove Old Server2008 DC Offsite

Tags: active-directory

we (still) have an outdated Domain with Server 2008 DCs. There are 3 of them.
One DC, which was from a remote (VPN) location, is now on my desk in main office.

The goal is to demote and remove it from Domain.
Since the network onsite is different (10.1.30.xxx) from the VPN location (10.2.30.xxx), I cannot connect it to the LAN. Also, afaik, I cannot do a temporary routing without disturbing the VPN location. Also I may not change the IP of the DC (one never should do this)

Should I offsite remove the DC (like this https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/itops-talk-blog/step-by-step-manually-removing-a-domain-controller-server/ba-p/280564 ) or can i somehow connect it to local LAN?

I would rather remove it "online", since the DC itself starts normally. It has been offline for several weeks, though.

shipping it back to the VPN location is not possible.

Thanks!
David

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove Old Server2008 DC Offsite](https://serverfault.com/questions/1053112/remove-old-server2008-dc-offsite)

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Boot the domain controller, change the ip address (perfectly fine) and reconnect it to your environment. If you believe that there is a slight risk that the single domain controller was running in a split-brain scenario, then don't do this.
2. Remove it manually and do a metadata cleanup as in the article you found. However, I'd rather search the official docs for the procedure and check if the author went along the best practice.